# Fitting blocks inside a container the best possible way

Tags: javascript, image, css

I have a container with a fixed size (H x W)

Im getting images and based on the amount of them I want to fit them into this container the best possible way, but keeping in mind that the latest image must be the biggest, and so forth for lets say the first 3 images, there after they can all be the same size.

The images all have the same size, or rather ratio, lets say 640x480. Perhaps I could somehow crop them to fit better?

Im using javascript only for this, and css of course.

So i will have many scenarios for example:

1 image - takes up the whole space
2 images - 50% 50% for both
3 images - image 1 biggestm image 2 and 3 the same?
4 images - images 1 biggest, then 2, then 3, then 4 smallest

etc

This is just an idea..

[image: One image only]
[image: One image only]
    [image: enter code here]

Comment: A diagram would be helpful.

Comment: Ok, I added some. So I trying to figure out how to fit boxes in side a fixed sized box. But wanting to have a sort of hierarchy of size

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17070570/fitting-random-sized-images-into-div-leaving-no-spaces